# PowerShell script to identify hiding (MZ) executables via inspection - Errors

Tags: powershell, variables, scripting, nested, file-extension

I was searching the web for examples to identify hiding DLLs and EXEs given a specified directory. I came across the following code and decided to give it a shot as it seemed to be exactly what I need:

```
    #add extensions here to ignore
    $ignore_extensions = '.exe','.dll'

    #grab all items in the current directory
    $mylisting = Get-ItemProperty *

    Write-Host("Number of files/folders:")$mylisting.count
    $count_suspect = 0
    for($i=0;$i -lt $mylisting.count; $i++)
    {
         #for each item in the listing: ensure the item is not a directory and not an ignored extension
         if( (Test-Path $mylisting[$i] -PathType Leaf) -and ($mylisting[$i].extension -notin $ignore_extensions) )
         {

              $magicbytes = '{0:X2}' -f (Get-Content $myfiles[$i] -Encoding Byte -ReadCount 4)
              if($magicbytes -eq '4D 5A 90 00')
              {
                   write-host("Found atypical file:")$myfiles[$i]
                   $count_suspect++
              }
         }
    }
    Write-Host("Number of suspect files found:")$count_suspect
```

The example output given was:

```
    Number of files/folders: 27
    Found atypical file: C:\ps.txt
    Found atypical file: C:\PsExec.exe.txt

    Number of Suspect files found: 2
```

If anyone has a moment to help understand the process so I can figure out how to make this work, I'd be very appreciative.

**update**

When a directory matches false for identifying files with the MZ byte sequences, it works without error and prints what is expected:

```
    Number of files/folders: 16
    Number of suspect files found: 0
```

When a directory matches true for identifying files with the MZ byte sequences, I get the following errors:

```
    Cannot index into a null array.
    At C:\Users\nog\Desktop\find_magic_bytes.ps1:15 char:11
    + $magicbytes = '{0:X2}' -f (Get-Content $myfiles[1] -Encoding Byte -R ...
    +~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       +CategoryInfo         : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
       +FullQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

Comment: I think someone just refactored a variable incompletely. Inside your `if` statement, replace `$myfiles` by `$mylisting` and it should work.